# Which file to locate to see data of database in SQLite browser

Tags: sqlite

I'm creating a database "UserDataBase.db" and while opening this in SQLite browser neither data nor tables is being shown if I am doing any CRUD operations then it works.I am providing images link also regarding which file I am locating in SQLite browser.First I am synchronizing these files and saving on Desktop and opening in SQLite browser.I have tried to fetch the data from the database it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the database is just 4k and that the -wal file is 80.5k the data hasn't been written/comitted. You need to close the database or [checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) the database and then copy the file. Or you could copy the -wal and -shm files into DB Browser open it and then close it and then re-open it.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT answer can you just tell me is there is any function to close the database.I am using sqlite3.

Comment: @NamrataSanger I don know reactive, for normal Android SDK you just close the SQLiteDatabase. At a guess from a quick look you if use `var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'appdb.db',createFromLocation: '~appdb.db'})` the you close with db.close();